# Which datatype can be used to store videos in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to store videos, images and long text in SQL Server 2005. Which datatype is the best suit for videos, images and long text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store data like that in the filesystem, and store a path in the database. Much easier to scale , much easier to manage and backup, and much faster.

If you *must* store it in the DB, `VARBINARY(MAX)` will work (but, seriously, do the filesystem thing)

Comment: Can you give any links that shows how to use and work with filesystem

Comment: Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` for long **binary** data (video, images) and `VARCHAR(MAX)` for long (> 8000 characters) **text** data

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea to store video in database, just store it on file system and save the link/url to database.

Example :
User(user_id(PK), name, pass, bla bla bla....)
Video(video_id(PK), user_id(FK), video_url)

So in your application, try to save the video to some folder, like http://example.com/assets/video/7468647.avi

then save '7468647.avi' to Video table

UPDATE : the video_url may be text or character varying, it's depend on your system needs